# removing (small) whitespace between HTML table cells

Tags: html

How do I remove the (small) whitespace between table cells? I've tried 3 things to no avail

```html
<html>
    <!-- How to remove white space between table cells? -->
    <style>
td { background-color : #888888; border-collapse : collapse; border-width : 0px; padding : 0px; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: unwanted whitespace between table cells]

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`.
By default table have some paddings, by tags from the example above you can set it to 0.

```html
<html>
    <!-- How to remove white space between table cells? -->
    <style>
td { background-color : #888888; border-collapse : collapse; border-width : 0px; padding : 0px; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `border-collapse: collapse;` property is for `table` not `td`. Check this:

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td { background-color : #888888; padding : 0px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)